# "java.lang.InternalError: Unexpected CryptoAPI failure generating seed" during silent installation

Tags: install4j

We are installing our product via script for automated UI tests.
Sometimes the installation failes with the following error.

> java.lang.InternalError: Unexpected CryptoAPI failure generating seed
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativeSeedGenerator.getSeedBytes(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.generateSeed(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.lambda$static$0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.getEntropyInput(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.getEntropyInput(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.instantiateIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.engineNextBytes(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.engineNextBytes(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg$SeederHolder.lambda$static$0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.getEntropyInput(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.getEntropyInput(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.instantiateIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.engineNextBytes(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg.engineNextBytes(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/sun.security.provider.DRBG.engineNextBytes(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.next(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.Random.nextLong(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.io.File$TempDirectory.generateFile(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
>       at com.exe4j.runtime.util.WinDel.scheduleDeletion(WinDel.java:85)
>       at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher$3.run(WinLauncher.java:118)

Is there any known bug or fix for this?

Comment: This looks like a problem with the JRE, not with install4j.

Comment: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/security/provider/NativeSeedGenerator.java
there is the code that throws the exception.
No idea how it can happen

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Oracle Weblogic. Adding the following to the java options helped me

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```